# Iterating array for each item in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays

I have an array of objects and I want to loop in throught **once**. This is the code of javascript.

```
   data.projectModelList.sum = function (prop) {
           var total = 0;
           for (var i = 0, _len = this.length; i < _len; i++) {
              total += this[i][prop];
           }
           return total;
        }

        vm.dataTotal = [data.projectModelList.sum("budget"),
                        data.projectModelList.sum("tax"),
                        data.projectModelList.sum("money"),
                        data.projectModelList.sum("balance"),
                        data.projectModelList.sum("amount"),
                        data.projectModelList.sum("current"),
                        data.projectModelList.sum("after"),
                        data.projectModelList.sum("discount")]
```

When I loop through I get budget, tax, money, balance, amount, current, after, discount more than 1. I just wanna loop it through and then the result must be every item display once and not more. I know I need to change something in the for loop but I don't know what.

Kind regards

EDIT:

ModelItem

```
  public class ProjectDashBoardModel
   {
      public decimal budget { get; set; }
      public decimal tax{ get; set; }
      public decimal money{ get; set; }
      public decimal balance{ get; set; }
      public decimal amount{ get; set; }
      public decimal current{ get; set; }
      public decimal after{ get; set; }
      public decimal discount{ get; set; }     
   }

   public class ProjectDashboard
   {
      public Guid Id { get; set; }
      public string ProjectLogo { get; set; }
      public string LastMutatedBy { get; set; }
      public DateTime LastMutatedDate { get; set; }
      public List<ProjectDashBoardModel> ProjectModelList { get; set; }


   }
```

Comment: please add the structure of `projectModelList`.

Comment: The structure of the modelitem

Comment: it does not look like javascript. and has different names.

Comment: I put the ProjectDashboardModel into a list server sided with C#. I get the data through a dataservice of javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your `sum` function to return an object with *all* the sums as properties - this means you'd only have to loop the array once.

```
data.projectModelList.sum = function (props) {
       var total = {};
       for (var i = 0, _len = this.length; i < _len; i++) {
         for(var j=0;j<props.length;i++){
          var prop = props[j];
          if(total[prop] === undefined){
              total[prop] = 0;
          }
          total[prop] += this[i][prop];
         }
       }
       return total;
    }
```

You would call it with an array of all the properties you want:

```
var sums = data.projectModelList.sum(['budget','tax','money']);
```

And then you would read the sum using dot or bracket notation

```
var budgetTotal = sums.budget;
var moneyTotal = sums['money'];
```